# How to sort a value alphabeticaly in a dropdownlist? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listitem

I am trying to sort values in a dropdown , here is my code

```
   For Each Keystring as Long in HashValue.Keys 
      Dim LItem As New ListItem
      LItem.Text = cw.Name.ToString()
      LItem.Value = Keystring.ToString
      ddRole.Items.Add(LItem)
   Next
```

I tried LItem.Sort. but Sort was not defined property.

let me know the best way to sort values. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just using [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)?

```
 For Each Keystring as Long in HashValue.Keys.OrderBy(Function(key) key) 
      Dim LItem As New ListItem
      LItem.Text = cw.Name.ToString()
      LItem.Value = Keystring.ToString
      ddRole.Items.Add(LItem)
 Next
```

Answer (score 1):

the quick way is to put your `ListItem` into a `List`. Then sort that list using the default List `.sort()` method. Then bind it to your dropdown.

```
dim ddList as List(Of ListItem)
For Each Keystring as Long in HashValue.Keys 
    Dim LItem As New ListItem
    LItem.Text = cw.Name.ToString()
    LItem.Value = Keystring.ToString
    ddList.add(LItem)
Next

ddList.Sort()
ddRole.DataSource = ddList
ddRole.DataBind()
```

Comment: What is 'For Each Keystring as Long in HashValue.Keys' used for in this, I don't understand, Old post but I'm having trouble hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Try with lambda:

```
Items2Sort.Sort(function(x1,x2) x1.CompareTo(x2))
```

Of course if item is a string.